# jQuery: How to use the same widget multiple times on a single page

Tags: jquery-ui, radio-button, widget

jQuery UI seems to be sensitive to the attributes of the elements that compose a widget. How then can I use the same widget mutiple times in a single page\form?

Example - the radio select widget, which comes in the demo index.html file that downloads with jQuery-ui:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head> 
        ...
        $(function(){
            $("#radioset").buttonset();
        }
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <form style="margin-top: 1em;"> 
            <div id="radioset"> 
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
                <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label> 
                <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
            </div> 
        </form> 
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

What code then should I add to have a second div with a different set of radio buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $(function(){
            $("#radioset2").buttonset();
        }
<div id="radioset2">
```

Or you could use

```
$(".radioset").buttonset();
```

Wich would select the radioset class not the id so you could have many.

To address your comment:

```
$(function(){
                $("#radioset1").buttonset();
                $("#radioset2").buttonset();
            }

<form name="form1" style="margin-top: 1em;"> 
            <div id="radioset1"> 
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
                <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label> 
                <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
            </div> 
</form>
<form name="form2" style="margin-top: 1em;"> 
            <div id="radioset2"> 
                    <input type="radio" id="radioAgain1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radioAgain2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label> 
                    <input type="radio" id="radioAgain3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
                </div> 
        </form>
```

I see no reason for the above not to work.

Comment: Pretty sure jquery needs them to be something1 something2. Try it out. You CAN have many radiosets on a page its trivial.

Comment: You're right but with one critical addition - the two radio sets need to be in seperate forms, or else all the radio buttons are tied together. Actually I don't see the logic in that, but I tested it and that was the differentiating element. @lznogood - do the change and I'l accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks!!  It seems absurd that you have to wrap this in a form. weird gotcha.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't actually require the form to be wrapped around.  Instead, you just need to make sure your radio groups have different names. It's explained in greater detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276640/jquery-ui-when-using-multiple-buttonsets-radio-buttons-they-forget-their-stat) .

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you want, along with an example of how to put 2 different radio sets into one form. Notice the NAME of the inputs

```
$(function(){
            $(".radioset").buttonset();
        }
<form name="form1" style="margin-top: 1em;"> 
    <div id="radioset1" class="radioset"> 
        <input type="radio" id="radioset1-1" name="radio1" /><label for="radioset1-1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioset1-2" name="radio1" checked="checked" /><label for="radioset1-2">Choice 2</label> 
        <input type="radio" id="radioset1-3" name="radio1" /><label for="radioset1-3">Choice 3</label>
    </div> 
    <div id="radioset2" class="radioset"> 
        <input type="radio" id="radioset2-1" name="radio2" /><label for="radioset2-1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioset2-2" name="radio2" checked="checked" /><label for="radioset2-2">Choice 2</label> 
        <input type="radio" id="radioset2-3" name="radio2" /><label for="radioset2-3">Choice 3</label>
    </div> 
</form>
```